# Allow a prerequisite to be installed only on Windows 8 using Advanced Installer

Tags: sqlite, prerequisites, advanced-installer

I have developed an installer using Advanced Installer.I want that the SQLite package that I have added as a prerequisite should only be shown on Windows 8 and not on any other Operating Systems.Can this be achieved using Advanced Installer?
If yes please help

Regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this from the [Install Conditions tab](http://www.advancedinstaller.com/user-guide/prerequisites-install-conditions.html), uncheck all systems from the tree **Supported WIndows Versions** making sure that only Windows 8 remains selected.

Comment: What I meant is if I am adding sqlite.msi file as a prerequisite to the my main(.exe) installation,that prerequisite should be shown only on windows 8.The main installer package(.exe) should run on any platform.I hope my doubt is clear

Comment: Yes Vivek, I understood that. From the Install Conditions page you can select only the supported OS-es for that specific prerequisite, not for the main package. For the main installer you can specify on which OS to run from Launch Conditions page (found below Prerequisites page), these are different settings.

Comment: Thanks :-) and what about downloading the update from the server.I still couldn't fix the issue

Comment: regarding the update, send me an email with the projects on support@advancedinstaller.com , so I can see what is the problem exactly